# Oracle: Return Large Dataset with Cursor in Procedure

Tags: oracle, performance, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've seen lots of posts regarding the use of cursors in PL/SQL to return data to a calling application, but none of them touch on the issue I believe I'm having with this technique. I am fairly new to Oracle, but have extensive experience with MSSQL Server. In SQL Server, when building queries to be called by an application for returning data, I usually put the SELECT statement inside a stored proc with/without parameters, and let the stored proc execute the statement(s) and return the data automatically. I've learned that with PL/SQL, you must store the resulting dataset in a cursor and then consume the cursor.

We have a query that doesn't necessarily return huge amounts of rows (~5K - 10K rows), however the dataset is very wide as it's composed of 1400+ columns. Running the SQL query itself in SQL Developer returns results instantaneously. However, calling a procedure that opens a cursor for **the same query** takes 5+ minutes to finish.

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PROCNAME(RESULTS OUT SYS_REFCURSOR)
AS
BEGIN    
    OPEN RESULTS FOR
    <SELECT_query_with_1400+_columns>
    ...
END;
```

After doing some debugging to try to get to the root cause of the slowness, I'm leaning towards the cursor returning one row at a time very slowly. I can actually see this real-time by converting the proc code into a PL/SQL block and using `DBMS_SQL.return_result(RESULTS)` after the SELECT query. When running this, I can see each row show up in the Script output window in SQL Developer one at a time. If this is exactly how the cursor returns the data to the calling application, then I can definitely see how this is the bottleneck as it could take 5-10 minutes to finish returning all 5K-10K rows. If I remove columns from the SELECT query, the cursor displays all the rows much faster, so it does seem like the large amount of columns is an issue using a cursor.

Knowing that running the SQL query by itself returns instant results, how could I get this same performance out of a cursor? It doesn't seem like it's possible. Is the answer putting the embedded SQL in the application code and not using a procedure/cursor to return data in this scenario? We are using Oracle 12c in our environment.

Edit: Just want to address how I am testing performance using the regular SELECT query vs the PL/SQL block with cursor method:

SELECT (takes ~27 seconds to return ~6K rows):

```sql
SELECT <1400+_columns>
FROM <table_name>;
```

PL/SQL with cursor (takes ~5-10 minutes to return ~6K rows):

```sql
DECLARE RESULTS SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
    OPEN RESULTS FOR
    SELECT <1400+_columns>
    FROM <table_name>;

    DBMS_SQL.return_result(RESULTS);
END;
```

Some of the comments are referencing what happens in the console application once all the data is returned, but I am only speaking regarding the performance of the two methods described above within Oracle\SQL Developer. Hope this helps clarify the point I'm trying to convey.

Comment: Every SELECT statement is processed via a cursor (implicit). Have you tried an Oracle pipelined function?

Comment: Can you show what exactly you do with the cursor (or the data it returns)? In fact, there should be no difference in running a pure SQL statement and opening a cursor of the same query.

Comment: @TurtlesAllTheWayDown - have not heard of "pipelined" function but will check it out now.

Comment: @PavelSmirnov Nothing else is done with the cursor on the database side. We call the procedure from a .NET application and work with the data returned, eventually writing it to a file.

Comment: @GuillermoGarcia, that's it, you "work with the data". The question is - what exactly you do with it. Also note that "fast retrieval" in SQL Developer can be false, since by default it's configured to return only 50 rows (you can test it scrolling the result set).

Comment: @PavelSmirnov I am only talking about the performance of returning the data. With SQL statement, returning all the rows (5K+) not just the default 50, takes 27 seconds. Returning through procedure/cursor takes 5+ minutes.

Comment: @GuillermoGarcia, as I already mentioned, there is no difference in running a SQL query and opening a cursor inside PL/SQL block for that same query. Moreover, *opening* a cursor has almost no impact on performance. The DB starts serving your query once you start *reading* the data. So, my guess, the performance issue is somewhere on the side. And it's hard to tell what it is exactly without additional details.

Comment: *"With SQL statement, returning all the rows (5K+) not just the default 50, takes 27 seconds. Returning through procedure/cursor takes 5+ minutes"* This sounds like a problem with the code which **consumes the cursor**. It's nothing to do with the stored procedure you've posted here. Please post the code which reads (fetches) rows from the cursor and maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: Did you consider paging your request? Returning such a dataset will obviously overload the cache

Comment: PLSQL is slower than pure SQL, your options are to page it, create your file on PLSQL side then pass it to .NET, do a pipelined function with reasonable return size, convert to a view (or write to a table, a cache, then use that to get data on .NET side) or seriously reconsider your approach because maybe there is no reason to return so many rows at once

Comment: Thanks for all the input so far. I've added some details regarding the two methods I'm comparing performance against (straight SELECT vs SELECT in PL/SQL block with cursor). The .NET application needs the entire dataset to move forward with the rest of the process. Paging the results in this scenario is not applicable. Maybe writing the query output to a temp table and subsequently doing a pure SELECT * FROM <tmp_table> might help with returning the entire set faster. I just don't see how continuing to use a cursor will solve the issue as that seems to be the bottleneck.

Comment: You may be under a misconception. You wrote in your question: _Running the SQL query itself in SQL Developer returns results instantaneously._ That's because _SQL Developer_ only fetches the first few rows and displays them. In other words, it paginates the query result set whereas your .NET code probably returns the entire result set at one go.

Comment: @Abra - reiterating what I've mentioned already. Yes, the SELECT returns the first 50 records instantaneously in SQL Developer. It takes ~27 seconds to return all 6K+ records vs cursor approach which takes 5+ minutes to return the same data.

Comment: Hiding queries in stored procedures is not very common in the Oracle world (and I don't think it actually achieves anything). If you want to hide the complexity of a query, create a view and select from the view. It won't get more efficient than that.

Answer (score 0):

You can run a SQL Monitor report for the two executions of the SQL; that will show you exactly where the time is being spent.  I would also consider running the two approaches in separate snapshot intervals and checking into the output from an AWR Differences report and ADDM Compare Report; you'd probably be surprised at the amazing detail these comparison reports provide. 
Also, even though > 255 columns in a table is a "no-no" according to Oracle as it will fragment your record across > 1 database blocks, thus increasing the IO time needed to retrieve the results, I suspect the differences in the two approaches that you are seeing is not an IO problem since in straight SQL you report fast result fetching all.  Therefore, I suspect more of a memory problem.  As you probably know, PL/SQL code will use the Program Global Area (PGA), so I would check the parameter pga_aggregate_target and bump it up to say 5 GB (just guessing).  An ADDM report run for the interval when the code ran will tell you if the advisor recommends a change to that parameter.